# Java hibernate: @OneToMany association doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my code i have a `oneToMany` relation between `customer` class and `item` class. This means that, **a customer may have one or many items.**
Here is the customer code:

```
@Entity
@Data

public class customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    String name;
    String lastname;

    @Embedded
    Address address;

    @OneToMany
     @Column(name="ITEM_ID")
    List<item> item;    
}
```

and it's the item class:

```
@Entity
@Data

public class item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    String name;
    String Serialnumber;
    int price;

    @ManyToOne
    customer customer;

}
```

Then i have made some tests to try my queries in the models.

```
insert into item(id,name,Serialnumber,price) values(1,'bike','123',200);
insert into item(id,name,Serialnumber,price) values(2,'car','123',200);


insert into customer(id,name,lastname,Country,City,Street,No,item_id) 
values(1,'Salman','Lashkarara','Iran','Tehran','Shariati','12',1);

insert into customer(id,name,lastname,Country,City,Street,No,item_id) 
values(2,'Saba','Lashkarara','Iran','Tehran','Shariati','12',2);


insert into customer(id,name,lastname,Country,City,Street,No,item_id) 
values(3,'Saba','Lashkarara','Iran','Tehran','Shariati','12',1);
```

But when i run my code, i face with the following error:

```
Column "ITEM_ID" not found; SQL statement:
insert into customer(id,name,lastname,Country,City,Street,No,item_id) values(1,'Salman','Lashkarara','Iran','Tehran','Shariati','12',1)
```

Please pay especial attention, that it is a `java mvc-spring` application and i create my models using the code, so **there is no database to check the field item_id**.

As you can see i have already added the `@Column(name="ITEM_ID")` to define the column.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. A customer can have multiple items. So it is not possible that the reference(s) to the items are in the customer table. The mapping you posted here does most likely created  n:m mapping table between customer and item. If you use the mappedBy attribute than the reference could be in the item table (as a reference to the customer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`@JoinColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) for association columns:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
List<item> item;
```

Comment: If I am correct the Item_id colum is than in the item table and you querry tries to insert it into the customer table.

Comment: Probably you have to change/rebuild the schema to reflect the mapping changes.

Answer (score 0):

some other options

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.All, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
List<item> item;
```

in Item class

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="item")
customer customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this i also have `user` class and `bcr` class, one user have many bcr so below code will help you

**bcr.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_who_enter_demand", nullable = false)
    public User getUserByUserWhoEnterDemand() {
    return this.userByUserWhoEnterDemand;
    }

    public void setUserByUserWhoEnterDemand(User userByUserWhoEnterDemand) {
    this.userByUserWhoEnterDemand = userByUserWhoEnterDemand;
    }
```

**user.java**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByUserWhoEnterDemand")
    public Set<BudgetControlRegister> getBudgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand() {
    return this.budgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand;
    }

    public void setBudgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand(Set<BudgetControlRegister> budgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand) {
    this.budgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand = budgetControlRegistersForUserWhoEnterDemand;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't map a table column without table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_TABLE")
public class item {
...
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID_ITEM_TABLE") 
 private customer customer;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_TABLE")
public class customer {
...
  @OneToMany
  @Column(name="ITEM_ID")
  List<item> item;    
}
```